# Can't access property of Stripe customer_create response

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm using the following Stripe library which integrates with the Stripe api: https://github.com/bcessa/php-stripe

In my controller I'm creating the customer

```
$customer = $this->stripe->customer_create($token, $customerEmail);

// This returns undefined property error
echo $customer->id;
```

It returns a valid php object, but I cannot access the the values. Also, the customer is being created correctly on the Stripe service.

Comment: I see in the library that there's not a function called `create_customer()`, but there is a `customer_create()`. Is this a mistype in the question?

Comment: Are you sure the API call was successful?

Comment: Yes, if I do a print_r($customer) directly after the customer_create() I get a full response with all of the correct data.

Comment: Can you post the result of `print_r($customer)`? If the data is there, then `$customer->id` is likely an incorrect way to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this PHP library returns the data in JSON.  I saw somewhere else that Stripe handled the decoding, but in this case it looks like it didn't.  Had to add the following code.

```
$customer = json_decode($this->stripe->customer_create($token, $customerEmail));
echo $customer->id;
```